# How do i add racing wheel to my Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to figure out how to get a steeringwheel-control to a Unity-project. I made a 3D racing game and bought: Ferrari Racing Wheel Red Legend Edition. And i want to learn how i can add the steering wheel to the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just like any joystick and you can configure it in the Input Manager.

Methods like Input.GetAxis(), Input.GetKey() etc. should work without a problem.

More on the input manager:

- [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)
- [Conventional Game Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html)

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark it as an answer if you think it solves your problem.